# Keep vagrant database data after vagrant destroy

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vagrant

What is the best/acceptable practice for keeping database data after a Vagrant destroy?

Should I create a shared folder for my database data? If so where (by default) does ubuntu store such data?

I forgot to mention my host and guest OS' are Ubuntu and am referring to MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the RDBMS you use.

For MySQL on Ubuntu, you can simply backup (`tar` or `rsync` to a remote host) the /var/lib/mysql folder (when mysql is NOT running) and its configuration files `/etc/mysql`.

For PostgreSQL it is similar, the database files are normally under cd `/usr/local/pgsql/data`. Refer to [File System level backup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/backup-file.html)

> NOTE: avoid using the default `vboxsf` to share large number of files between guest and host because it has known performance issues.

Answer (score 5):

I needed a way to backup my database whenever I `vagrant destroy` the instance or if something happened with the box and I needed to kill the process thus loosing data. I primarily work with CMS systems and having the backend database persisted is very important.

I'm already sharing a `db` folder that contains a sql file that is used when provisioning. I installed the `vagrant-triggers` plugin and have it running a mysqldump.sh script file whenever I run the `vagrant destroy` command.

`config.trigger.before :destroy do
    info "Dumping the database before destroying the VM..."
    run_remote  "bash /home/vagrant/db/mysqldump.sh"
  end`

The mysqldump.sh file runs a mysqldump command to a separate backup.sql file.

`mysqldump -u root database > /home/vagrant/db/backup.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Mapping database data outside the box seems a good solution:

[[Homestead] Ideas on persisting databases upon vagrant destroy](http://laravel.io/forum/06-07-2014-homestead-ideas-on-persisting-databases-upon-vagrant-destroy?page=1#reply-19386)